# os.system or subprocess to pass command to shell

Tags: python, subprocess, redirect, os.system

I am trying to execute a command in a shell and pipe the output at the same time for filtering.

the relevent code looks like:

```
import os
n=raw_input("enter cmd")
os.system(n + ' | grep x')
```

the result is

```
Syntax error: Redirection unexpected.
```

It is on ubuntu, seemed like some references online mentioned this, but none I could directly associate. Seems like subprocess may help, but most examples are as of yet beyond my current understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu, the default shell is `dash`, and that is the error it gives you if you start a line with `|`, so I'm guessing you didn't put anything in `n`.

`os.system()` is deprecated now. The `subprocess` module is much more powerful and preferred. You would have to invest some time in reading the docs on it, but it pays off. It has some handy "convenience functions" to reduce the work needed.

Comment: TZ, this was very helpful. It helped me put a number of breaks using some print statements and reason through. I was able to prove that the output was printed to the screen, th(like I said very much a newbie)en the "| grep x". I am learning non-scientific programming and python at the same time (like I said very much a newbie). I

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is `os.system()` deprecated?  Seems like it provides a very quick and easy interface for when you just want to pass a command to the system without needing to invest any time in learning how to use the more complicated `subprocess` module...

Answer (score 2):

[Use ***subprocess*** module instead of os.system, which is deprecated](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements).

[***subprocess***](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) allows piping and capturing stdout, as you want.

```
process = subprocess.call(command_string.split(), ..., stdout=subprocess.PIPE, ...) 

... handle your output from process.communicate()
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe it's in this command, I am just a little new to it. I will keep looking for examples and it might help...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error from the shell, not python. You most likely did not enter a command, so the system call was only " | grep x", which would return an error such as that.